# N x M repeated measures chi square

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, repeated-measures

I have data that is essentially a repeated measures chi square with 8 choices measured 5 times

```r
library("descr")     
library("lsr")

chidata <- matrix(c(129, 67, 113, 11, 41, 3, 12, 23, 79, 37, 99, 28, 
     42, 2, 10, 4, 48, 43, 44, 29, 39, 3, 10, 2, 18, 13, 12, 17, 25, 
     3, 10, 1, 5, 7, 2, 6, 7, 10, 10, 10), nrow=8, ncol=5)

chidata

CrossTable(chidata,  mcnemar = T, chisq = T, resid = T, sresid = T, asresid = T)
```

While the Pearson chi square can be produced (even though there are 0s in the data, none of the expected values are 0, so it still runs), the McNemar cannot -- is there a way to run this as a repeated measures chi square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanded McNemar tests (sometimes called McNemar–Bowker), can fail if there are zeros in certain places in the table.  However, the test can be interpreted as an exact multinomial test, which won't have this problem. See [R Handbook: Tests for Paired Nominal Data](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_05.html) for an example.

However, the reason you cannot perform a McNemar test on your matrix is because it is not square.  This test makes no sense on a matrix that is not square.

I'm not sure what design your data come from, but McNemar isn't the right analysis.